# Get index of div

Tags: javascript

How to get index of the div I'm clicking using vanilla JS.
Is there a method or property for this like indexOf() or .selectedIndex ?

```js
function test() {
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
}
```

```css
div.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <div onclick="test()"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>
  <div onclick="test()"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>
  <div onclick="test()"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>
  <div onclick="test()"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Index of what in what? This is why jQuery exists.

Comment: add <div id="footer" > to every div you add so that you can differentiate between them and customise when you click each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass the div as a parameter, then use `parent.indexOf(child)`:

```js
function test(el) {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".flex div");
  var index = Array.from(divs).indexOf(el);
  console.log(index);
}
```

```css
div.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div onclick="test(this)"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>
  <div onclick="test(this)"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>
  <div onclick="test(this)"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>
  <div onclick="test(this)"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: lol. BTW, param name `e` is often used for an event, might be better to rename it to avoid confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by confusion? It is clear that an element will be passed. Anyways it's no more than a letter :)

Comment: I'm just referring to a common naming convention used with event listener functions, which automatically receive the event as the argument.

Comment: `el.addEventListener("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... })`